# Marketplace site development: what skillset am I looking to hire?

Tags: web-development, website-design

I'd like to have a site built by a freelancer, but I don't know how to find the right person because I don't know which expertise/skill set would be best to look for given the functionality I'd like the site to have.

The site will be basically a marketplace for (a certain kind of) sound files. It will need the following:

a) users to be able to create logins and (simple) profiles

b) users to be able to upload MP3 or WAV files to the marketplace

c) users to be able to search for or browse all the files, and preview them for ~10 seconds; files organized by title or category

d) users to be able to buy (and then download) the files, and get paid when others purchase those they've uploaded

e) a rating system where people that have purchased a file can rate it based on a 5-star system, and also leave a brief (less than 140 character) review; highest rated files are displayed first for duplicates

Essentially I'm fairly new to web development (only basic HTML/CSS) and don't know how to bring a site like this together (i.e. what's necessary or optimal on the front and back ends) - and don't even know what to look for in a freelance web developer. Any suggestions would be MUCH appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Most business owners don't know what skills to look for in developers, but it's also generally a bad idea for a business owner with no experience in software development to try to have custom software created for them. In almost all cases, they get ripped off and end up with a really poor product. Instead, I'd recommend looking at existing e-commerce platforms to see if one might fit the bill. You'll have much better luck and it'll be waaaay cheaper than trying to hire a developer to build it for you.

Comment: If you really can't find anything that fits the bill (unlikely, since your requirements are pretty standard), then your best bet is to issue a few RFPs to different development studios and interactive agencies and see what they come back to you with. But generally developing new software completely from scratch takes a long time and a lot of money. I'd really recommend talking to an interactive agency that gives free consultations. They should be able to find you the best way to achieve your aims.